# CSR + KnockoutJS, add templates to few fields

Tags: client-side-rendering, knockoutjs

I am using examples from great article from here
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/888923/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms-p

and use example to add new Lookup value directly from form. It works, but don't understand how to implement this for **few** fields, for example if I have "SubType1" and "SubType2", and want same logic for "SubType2" field too

here is my example code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Rockietm/rjfk539f/

If You have lookup field "FieldSubType" than You see small "Add" link and input field if You press it:

[image]

But I am newbie with KnockoutJs, so how to add same functionality for **two** fields: for FieldSubType and for example SecondFieldSubType?

### **Update:**

Thank You!

So I put templates in one variable and can use it like

```
var keys = Object.keys(myFields);
console.log('myFields object contains ' + keys.length + ' keys: ' + keys);
```

But how to bind two models on same page? I tried to wrap-up in two  with 'with', like described here:
http://www.mytecbits.com/internet/knockout-js-binding-multiple-view-models

```
var html = "<div data-bind='with: Geography'>";
// ..
html += '</div>';
```

But no result, what I see is:

[image]

I have two fields: 'Geography' and 'Sub Type'. Here is my example code (it runs multiple times for every field but is is example):

```
 "use strict";

    if (!window.console) window.console = {};
    if (!window.console.log) window.console.log = function () { };

    var defaultLookupFieldTemplate = SPClientTemplates._defaultTemplates.Fields.default.all.all.Lookup.NewForm;

    var myFields = {
        'Geography': {
            NewForm: function (ctx) {
                var html = "<div data-bind='with: Geography'>";
                html += '<div id="myGeographyLookup" data-bind="visible: !editMode()">' + defaultLookupFieldTemplate(ctx);
                html += '<a href="javascript:void()" data-bind="click: addNewItem" title="Add new Geography item">Add</span>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<div data-bind="visible: editMode()">';
                html += '<input type="text" data-bind="value: newTitle" />';
                html += '<input type="button" data-bind="click: saveGeographyChanges, clickBubble: false" value="Save" title="Click and select new value from dropdown" />';
                html += '</div>';
                html += "</div>";

                return html;
            },
            EditForm: function (ctx) {
                var html = "<div data-bind='with: Geography'>";
                html += '<div id="myGeographyLookup" data-bind="visible: !editMode()">' + defaultLookupFieldTemplate(ctx);
                html += '<a href="javascript:void()" data-bind="click: addNewItem" title="Add new Geography item">Add</span>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<div data-bind="visible: editMode()">';
                html += '<input type="text" data-bind="value: newTitle" />';
                html += '<input type="button" data-bind="click: saveGeographyChanges, clickBubble: false" value="Save" title="Click and select new value from dropdown" />';
                html += '</div>';
                html += "</div>";
                return html;
            }
        },
        'Sub_x002d_type': {
            NewForm: function (ctx) {
                var html = "<div data-bind='with: Sub_x002d_type'>";
                html += '<div id="mySubtypeLookup" data-bind="visible: !editSubtypeMode()">' + defaultLookupFieldTemplate(ctx);
                html += '<a href="javascript:void()" data-bind="click: addNewSubtype" title="Add new Sub-type item">Add</span>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<div data-bind="visible: editSubtypeMode()">';
                html += '<input type="text" data-bind="value: newSubtypeTitle" />';
                html += '<input type="button" data-bind="click: saveSubtypeChanges, clickBubble: false" value="Save" title="Click and select new value from dropdown" />';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '</div>';
                return html;
            },
            EditForm: function (ctx) {
                var html = "<div data-bind='with: Sub_x002d_type'>";
                html += '<div id="mySubtypeLookup" data-bind="visible: !editSubtypeMode()">' + defaultLookupFieldTemplate(ctx);
                html += '<a href="javascript:void()" data-bind="click: addNewSubtype" title="Add new Sub-type item">Add</span>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<div data-bind="visible: editSubtypeMode()">';
                html += '<input type="text" data-bind="value: newSubtypeTitle" />';
                html += '<input type="button" data-bind="click: saveSubtypeChanges, clickBubble: false" value="Save" title="Click and select new value from dropdown" />';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '</div>';
                return html;
            }
        }
    }

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

        OnPostRender: function (ctx) {

            var pageModel = {
                'Geography': {
                    editMode: ko.observable(false),
                    newTitle: ko.observable(''),
                    addNewItem: function () {
                        this.editMode(true);
                    },

                    saveGeographyChanges: function () {
                        // .. some logic
                        console.log("Added 'Geography' lookup");
                        this.editMode(false);
                    }
                },
                'Sub_x002d_type': {
                    editSubtypeMode: ko.observable(false),
                    newSubtypeTitle: ko.observable(''),
                    addNewSubtype: function () {
                        this.editSubtypeMode(true);
                    },
                    saveSubtypeChanges: function () {
                        // some logic here
                        console.log("Added Sub-Type lookup");
                        this.editSubtypeMode(false);
                    }
                }
            };

            // How to do it?..
            ko.applyBindings(pageModel);
        },
        Templates: {
            Fields: myFields
        }
    });
```

> Also note your CSR is not MDS proof

Thank You, but Publishing Features are enabled on this site, so MDS does not fire here

### **Update2:**

Also tried to bind by ID, but no result:

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
OnPostRender: function (ctx) {

    var pageModel1 = {
            editMode: ko.observable(false),
            newTitle: ko.observable(''),
            addNewItem: function () {
                this.editMode(true);
            },

            saveGeographyChanges: function () {
                console.log("Added 'Geography' lookup");
                this.editMode(false);
            }
    };

    var pageModel2 = {

            editSubtypeMode: ko.observable(false),
            newSubtypeTitle: ko.observable(''),
            addNewSubtype: function () {
                this.editSubtypeMode(true);
            },
            saveSubtypeChanges: function () {
                console.log("Add Sub-Tupe lookup");
                this.editSubtypeMode(false);
            }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(pageModel1, document.getElementById("myGeographyLookup"));
    ko.applyBindings(pageModel2, document.getElementById("mySubtypeLookup"));
},
Templates: {
    Fields: myFields
}
```

});

### **Update3:**

I also tried to apply bindings outside of CSR:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("registerModel");
```

it works for first field('Geography'), but get "Uncaught TypeError: this.editSubtypeMode is not a function" editing 'Sub-type' field(

Don't understant how to apply bindings for two fields(

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Rockietm/bhrp79yu/

```
"use strict";

var defaultLookupFieldTemplate = SPClientTemplates._defaultTemplates.Fields.default.all.all.Lookup.NewForm;

var myFields = {
    'Geography': {
        NewForm: function(ctx) {

            var html = '<div id="myGeographyLookup" data-bind="visible: !editMode()">' + defaultLookupFieldTemplate(ctx);
            html += '<a href="javascript:void()" data-bind="click: addNewItem" title="Add new Geography item">Add</span>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div data-bind="visible: editMode()">';
            html += '<input type="text" data-bind="value: newTitle" />';
            html += '<input type="button" data-bind="click: saveGeographyChanges, clickBubble: false" value="Save" title="Click and select new value from dropdown" />';
            html += '</div>';

            return html;
        },
        EditForm: function(ctx) {

            var html = '<div id="myGeographyLookup" data-bind="visible: !editMode()">' + defaultLookupFieldTemplate(ctx);
            html += '<a href="javascript:void()" data-bind="click: addNewItem" title="Add new Geography item">Add</span>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div data-bind="visible: editMode()">';
            html += '<input type="text" data-bind="value: newTitle" />';
            html += '<input type="button" data-bind="click: saveGeographyChanges, clickBubble: false" value="Save" title="Click and select new value from dropdown" />';
            html += '</div>';

            return html;
        }
    },

    'Sub_x002d_type': {
        NewForm: function (ctx) {
            var html = '<div id="mySubtypeLookup" data-bind="visible: !editSubtypeMode()">' + defaultLookupFieldTemplate(ctx);
            html += '<a href="javascript:void()" data-bind="click: addNewSubtype" title="Add new Sub-type item">Add</span>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div data-bind="visible: editSubtypeMode()">';
            html += '<input type="text" data-bind="value: newSubtypeTitle" />';
            html += '<input type="button" data-bind="click: saveSubtypeChanges, clickBubble: false" value="Save" title="Click and select new value from dropdown" />';
            html += '</div>';

            return html;
        },
        EditForm: function (ctx) {
            var html = '<div id="mySubtypeLookup" data-bind="visible: !editSubtypeMode()">' + defaultLookupFieldTemplate(ctx);
            html += '<a href="javascript:void()" data-bind="click: addNewSubtype" title="Add new Sub-type item">Add</span>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div data-bind="visible: editSubtypeMode()">';
            html += '<input type="text" data-bind="value: newSubtypeTitle" />';
            html += '<input type="button" data-bind="click: saveSubtypeChanges, clickBubble: false" value="Save" title="Click and select new value from dropdown" />';
            html += '</div>';
            return html;
        }
    }
};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

    Templates: {
        Fields: myFields
    }
});

function registerModel() {

    var pageModel = {
        editMode: ko.observable(false),
        newTitle: ko.observable(''),
        addNewItem: function () {
            this.editMode(true);
        },

        saveGeographyChanges: function () {
            console.log("Added 'Geography' lookup");
            this.editMode(false);
        },

        editSubtypeMode: ko.observable(false),
        newSubtypeTitle: ko.observable(''),
        addNewSubtype: function () {
            this.editSubtypeMode(true);
        },

        saveSubtypeChanges: function () {
                console.log("Added Subtype lookup value");
                this.editSubtypeMode(false);
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(pageModel);
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("registerModel");
```

### **Resolved:**

Ok, thank You for answer! Finally defined knockout **outside** of csr. Ugly solution, but now it works and I added code for several fields:
https://jsfiddle.net/Rockietm/un4uvoh9/

```
function registerModel() {

    var pageModel = {
        editGeography: ko.observable(false),
        newGeography: ko.observable(''),
        addGeography: function() {
            this.editGeography(true);
        },

        saveGeographyChanges: function() {
            console.log("Added 'Geography' lookup");

            // some code to add new lookup item and populate and append child to dropdown..
            pageModel.editGeography(false);
        },

        editSubType: ko.observable(false),
        newSubType: ko.observable(''),
        addSubtype: function() {
            this.editSubType(true);
        },

        saveSubtypeChanges: function() {
            // ..
            pageModel.editSubType(false);
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(pageModel);
}

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

    Templates: {
        Fields: myFields
    }
});

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("registerModel");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the whole { } object you provide to CSR dynamically
most likely you will stuff it in one `myFields` Object with a definition for every field

Then instead of:

```
Templates: {
        Fields: {
            'FieldSubType':
```

you use it as:

```
Templates: {
        Fields: myFields
```

And in your OnPostRender function proces that whole Array again to dynamically configure all KnockOut

(ES5) JavaScripts' `Object.keys()` is your friend in all this

---

Also note your CSR is not MDS proof, use the [Cisar Chrome Extension](https://365csi.nl/cisar) to WYSIWYG write CSR code, it will give you the complete CSR boilerplate that is MDS save

--
Gennady G: deleted

Comment: Hi Danny! Thank You for answer. I moved fields inside variable but don't understand how to bind two models inside OnPostRender

Comment: You have to get the DOM elements **dynamically** and then apply KO **dynamically**... yes it is some advanced JS required.. its like driving one of my motorcycles... I can't teach you that by email... First time I did programming patterns like these it took me months